# How to traverse Directory with Distinguished Names

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

If I have a Directory Path (as well as the appropriate credentials) like:

```
LDAP://directory:389/DC=domain,DC=com
```

Which classes/methods can I use to access various objects by their Distinguished Name (DN) properties?  I have tried the `DirectoryEntry` class, but have not found any way to retrieve a `DirectoryEntry` object from a "base" object and a DN.

Example: having the Directory URL above, and the DN `CN=User,OU=Development,DC=domain,DC=com`, how can I access the `DirectoryEntry` (or similar) object for `LDAP://directory:389/CN=User,OU=Development,DC=domain,DC=com`?

I have seen some solutions involving string manipulation of the URL, but I'm looking for a way to accomplish this with normal .NET objects/classes.

Comment: Look into [SharpDirectory](https://bitbucket.org/sergiotapia/sharpdirectory) and if it doesn't offer what you were looking for please contribute! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my less-than-ideal method I'm using at the moment:

```
string GetNewDN(DirectoryEntry deBase, string DN)
{
    try
    {   // Handle the LDAP://example.com:389/DN=string formats
        return (new Uri(deBase.Path)).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/" + DN.Replace("/", @"\/");
    }
    catch (UriFormatException)
    {   // Handle the LDAP://DN=string formats
        return deBase.Path.Substring(0, deBase.Path.IndexOf(":")) + "://" + DN.Replace("/", @"\/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772152%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Here is an example :

```
DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://directory:389/CN=User,OU=Development,DC=domain,DC=com",
                                              "<adminAccountName>",
                                              "<adminPassword");
```

With a good tutorial [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/mhamilton/archive/2005/10/04/55920.aspx).

Comment: I don't have the exact LDAP path; from a `DirectoryEntry`, how do I retrieve another `DirectoryEntry` from just the DN?

Comment: So if I understand well your problem is just to transform DC=domain,DC=com (the "DC" part of the DN) into a DNS name to build "Directory" part of your URL ? It just a string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Could you use `DirectorySearcher` to search a subtree from a root `DirectoryEntry`?</strike>

This won't help as you note in your comment.  I don't think there's any substitute for parsing DirectoryEntry.Path, extracting the bits you need, and concatenating your DN, escaping any special characters in the DN if needed.

You need everything up to and including the third slash:

```
LDAP://server:port/relativePath
```

or the second slash if using serverless binding:

```
LDAP://relativePath
```

but there can be ambiguity if relativePath itself contains a slash (which will be escaped with a backslash).  So, as you say, string manipulation.

Comment: Maybe; how would I do that?  `new DirectorySearcher(DE).Filter = "(&(DN=CN=User,OU=Development,DC=domain,DC=com))"`?  I've tried something like that, but that doesn't work.

Comment: If I could use the `DirectorySearcher` to find my result, then I would have everything I need because the `SearchResult` objects have the `GetDirectoryEntry()` member function.

Comment: @palswim - you're right, dn isn't an attribute you can use in this way.  So I think you'll need to use the URL - the string manipulation you describe is just concatenation: "LDAP://server:port/" + distinguishedname, or if you're using serverless binding to AD, "LDAP://" + distinguishedName